# creating table with post information in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to create a table with the class name given by the user in my Android application. I tried to do it with following code but I get errors.

What's going wrong?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in","u975450189_****","********","u975450189_****");

$classname = $_POST["classname"];
$classid = $_POST["classid"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "CREATE TABLE ?(id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,? VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $classname, $classid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/u975450189/public_html/ClassCreate.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/u975450189/public_html/ClassCreate.php on line 11
> {"success":true}

Comment: Duplicate question, you can find your awnser here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228430/mysqli-throws-warning-mysqli-stmt-bind-param-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysql

Comment: i didnot understand that,i think my case is different whenever itry to create table with post info i am gettin error but when i want t insert any values it is working fine

Comment: @manoj: for adding code sample: just edit your post.

Comment: can someone please tell whats wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement) Also see [mysqli->prepare issue with creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266169/mysqli-prepare-issue-with-creating-tables).