# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in E:\UniServerZ\www\ospes\teacher.php on line 310

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Here is my code.

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['teacher'])){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}

              include('connection.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <style>
        .well {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url('img/noise4.png');
}
        table{
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td{
            border: 1px solid white;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        thead tr{
            background-color: #003333;
            color: white;
        }
        tbody tr{
            background-color: #007777;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body>


    <!-- CONTAINER STARTS -->
    <div class="container">
        <br /><br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <img src="img/logo.png" /><br /><br />
                <h2>Online Student Performence Evaluation System</h2>
        <h3>Teacher control panel</h3>
                </div>

  <p id="status">

      <?php
if(isset($_GET['status'])){
      if($_GET['status']=='successful'){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
    <strong>Successful!</strong> You have been logged in.
  </div>";

  }
}
      ?>

  </p>

        </div><br />

        <table class="text-center">
      <?php

        $qry = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT teacher_id, teacher_name FROM teachers WHERE teacher_id = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($qry, "s", $_SESSION['teacher']);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($qry);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($qry, $teacher_id, $teacher_name);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($qry);
        echo "<thead><tr><th class='text-center' colspan='2'>Teacher information</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td><td>".$teacher_id."</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td>".$teacher_name."</td></tr>
    </tbody>";

        ?>
  </table><br /><br />

        <div class="row well text-center">
        <h4>Add elements</h4><br />
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_exam_questions"><span class="glyphicon "></span> Add examination questions</button><br /><br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_exam_MCQs"><span class="glyphicon "></span> Add examination MCQs</button><br /><br />
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_categories"><span class="glyphicon "></span> Add categories</button><br /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_subjects"><span class="glyphicon "></span> Add subjects</button><br /><br />
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Add question html section starts -->
    <div id="add_exam_questions" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new question</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form" id="eform" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row-fluid">

       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esubject">Subject code:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="esubject" class="form-control" name="exam_subject" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="ename">Examination's name:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="ename" class="form-control" name="exam_name" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esession">Session:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="esession" class="form-control" name="exam_session" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="equestionid">Examination's question ID:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="equestionid" class="form-control" name="exam_question_id" required></div><br /><br />
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="equestion">Question:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><textarea id="equestion" class="form-control" name="exam_question" required></textarea></div><br /><br />
       </div>

       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Done</button></div><br />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
   <!-- Add question html section ends -->

    <!-- Add MCQ html section starts -->
    <div id="add_exam_MCQs" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new MCQ</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form" id="eform" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row-fluid">

       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esubject">Subject code:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="esubject" class="form-control" name="exam_subject" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="ename">Examination's name:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="ename" class="form-control" name="exam_name" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esession">Session:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="esession" class="form-control" name="exam_session" required></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="mlo">MCQ's learning outcome:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input id="mlo" class="form-control" name="MCQ_learning_outcome" required></div><br /><br />
       </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="eMCQ">MCQ:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><textarea id="eMCQ" class="form-control" name="exam_MCQ" required></textarea></div><br /><br />
       </div>

       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_MCQ"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Done</button></div><br />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
   <!-- Add MCQ html section ends -->

    <!-- Add exam html section starts -->
    <div id="add_exams" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new examination</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form" id="eform" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row-fluid">

       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="ename">Examination's name:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ename" name="exam_name" required /></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esubject">Subject code:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="esubject" name="exam_subject" maxlength="20" required /></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="esession">Session:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><select id="esession" class="form-control" name="exam_session" required><?php echo $sessionlist; ?></select></div><br /><br />
  </div>
       <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-form-label" for="edate">Examination's date:</label><div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="edate" name="exam_date" required /></div><br /><br /><br />
  </div>

       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Done</button></div><br />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
   <!-- Add exam html section ends -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        </body>
</html>


<?php

// Add php section starts

    // Add question php section starts
     if(isset($_POST['add_question'])){

          if(!empty($_POST['exam_subject']) && !empty($_POST['exam_name']) && !empty($_POST['exam_session']) && !empty($_POST['exam_question_id']) && !empty($_POST['exam_question'])){

    $exam_subject = $_POST['exam_subject'];
    $exam_name = $_POST['exam_name'];
    $exam_session = $_POST['exam_session'];
    $exam_question_id = $_POST['exam_question_id'];
    $exam_question = $_POST['exam_question'];
          $_POST['exam_subject']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_name']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_session']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_question_id']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_question']= NULL;

    $qry = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO exam_questions(subject_code, exam_name, session, question_id, question) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($qry, "sssss", $exam_subject, $exam_name, $exam_session, $exam_question_id, $exam_question);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($qry)){
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-success text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Successful!</strong> A new question has been added.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}else{
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-danger text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Failed!</strong> Try again.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}

          }else{
              echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-warning text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Caution!</strong> Enter all the fields.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
          }


             }
      //Add question php section ends

    // Add MCQ php section starts
     if(isset($_POST['add_MCQ'])){

          if(!empty($_POST['exam_subject']) && !empty($_POST['exam_name']) && !empty($_POST['exam_session']) && !empty($_POST['MCQ_learning_outcome']) && !empty($_POST['exam_MCQ'])){

    $exam_subject = $_POST['exam_subject'];
    $exam_name = $_POST['exam_name'];
    $exam_session = $_POST['exam_session'];
    $MCQ_learning_outcome = $_POST['MCQ_learning_outcome'];
    $exam_MCQ = $_POST['exam_MCQ'];
          $_POST['exam_subject']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_name']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_session']= NULL;
          $_POST['MCQ_learning_outcome']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_MCQ']= NULL;

    $qry = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO exam_mcqs(subject_code, exam_name, session, subject_learning_outcome, mcq) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($qry, "sssss", $exam_subject, $exam_name, $exam_session, $MCQ_learning_outcome, $exam_MCQ);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($qry)){
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-success text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Successful!</strong> A new MCQ has been added.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}else{
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-danger text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Failed!</strong> Try again.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}

          }else{
              echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-warning text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Caution!</strong> Enter all the fields.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
          }


             }
      //Add MCQ php section ends

    // Add exam php section starts
     if(isset($_POST['add_exam'])){

          if(!empty($_POST['exam_name']) && !empty($_POST['exam_subject']) && !empty($_POST['exam_session']) && !empty($_POST['exam_date'])){

    $exam_name = $_POST['exam_name'];
    $exam_subject = $_POST['exam_subject'];
    $exam_session = $_POST['exam_session'];
    $exam_question_id = $_POST['exam_question_id'];
    $question_learning_outcomes = $_POST['question_learning_outcomes'];
          $_POST['exam_name']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_subject']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_session']= NULL;
          $_POST['exam_question_id']= NULL;
          $_POST['question_learning_outcomes']= NULL;

    $qry = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO exams(exam_name, subject_code, session, exam_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($qry, "ssss", $exam_name, $exam_subject, $exam_session, $exam_date);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($qry)){
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-success text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Successful!</strong> A new examination has been added.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}else{
        echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-danger text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Failed!</strong> Try again.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
}

          }else{
              echo "<script>$('#status').html(".'"'."<div class='alert alert-warning text-center col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'><strong>Caution!</strong> Enter all the fields.</div>".'"'.");</script>";
          }


             }
      //Add exam php section ends

    // Add php section ends

// logout php section starts
     if(isset($_POST['logout'])){

         session_destroy();
         header("location: index.php");
         exit;

             }
      //logout php section ends

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
ob_end_flush();

    ?>
```

**The question and the mcq insert codes give the**

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in E:\UniServerZ\www\ospes\teacher.php on line 310
>   Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in E:\UniServerZ\www\ospes\teacher.php on line 311
>   error

Can't find anything wrong. Similar codes work fine in other pages. What is wrong here?

Comment: need to check error handling `mysqli_error`

Comment: Used every error checking functions but they return nothing.

Comment: post your connection.php file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228430/mysqli-throws-warning-mysqli-stmt-bind-param-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysql

Comment: <?php
$mysqli= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'kkk', '1234', 'ospes') or die('Connecion Failed');
?>

Comment: error reporting / check for errors vs. just plowing forward

Comment: I used mysqli_ping, mysqli_error, mysqli_stmt_error, mysqli_connect_error etc. but they return nothing. what else should I use?